# How to make new column in pandas based on condition from diffrent frame

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I'm trying make new column in pandas based on contdion.
I have table from dict with based information suche as below

```
Price_dict= {
    "Year" : [2023,2023],
    "Month" : [7,8],
    "Stala_EURO" : [1.27836,1.02323],
    "Stala_PLN" : [13.36200,20.23232],
}
df_price= pd.DataFrame(Price_dict)
```

Now I want add to table (dane) columns from df_price[['Stala_EURO','Stala_PLN']] based on specific condtion like this : if year = 2023 and month <= 7) take Stala_euro = 1.27836 and Stala_PLN = 13.36200 .etc

```
dane_slo = {
    "Year" : [2023,2023,2023,2023],
    "Month" : [7,8,7,10],
}
dane = pd.DataFrame(dane_slo)
```

I tried with np.where but in my case but that way doesn't work correctly

```
year= dane["Year"].values
mo= dane["Month"].values
ld = df_slo_CKT["Year"].values
lg = df_slo_CKT["Month"].values
x,y = np.where((year[:,None] == ld) & (month[:,None] < lg))

final= pd.concat([
    dane.loc[x,:].reset_index(drop=True),
    df_price.loc[y,["Stala_EURO","Stala_PLN"]]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
],axis=1)

print(final)
```

thanks you

Comment: can you make table of exact desired output? desired output is not clear.

Comment: `if year = 2023 and month <= 7) take Stala_euro = 1.27836 and Stala_PLN = 13.36200 .etc` what this `etc` means?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(dane.assign(key=pd.to_datetime(dane.assign(Day=1)))
                         .sort_values(by='key').reset_index(),
                     df_price
                      .assign(key=pd.to_datetime(df_price[['Year', 'Month']]
                                                 .assign(Day=1)))
                      .sort_values(by='key'),
                     on='key', suffixes=(None, '_')
                    )
         .set_index('index').sort_index()
        #.drop(columns=['key', 'Year_', 'Month_'])
      )
```

Output:

```
       Year  Month        key  Year_  Month_  Stala_EURO  Stala_PLN
index                                                              
0      2023      7 2023-07-01   2023       7     1.27836   13.36200
1      2023      8 2023-08-01   2023       8     1.02323   20.23232
2      2023      7 2023-07-01   2023       7     1.27836   13.36200
3      2023     10 2023-10-01   2023       8     1.02323   20.23232
```